# Background removal from webcam OPENCV PYTHON

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I'm creating a script that will read the state of a supermarket and tell me if there is products missing. 
for example in the image below there is some places where there is products missing. I'm using **FAST** method to find all the corners in the frame. but sometimes the scripts detects the floor  corners. What I want to do is remove the floor from the frame before I find the corners.

[image]
    import cv2
    import numpy as np

```
image = cv2.imread('gondola_imagem.jpeg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

fast = cv2.FastFeatureDetector_create()
# Obtain Key points, by default non max suppression is On
# to turn off set fast.setBool('nonmaxSuppression', False)
keypoints = fast.detect(gray, None)
print ("Number of keypoints Detected: ", len(keypoints))

image = cv2.drawKeypoints(image, keypoints, None, 
                          flags=cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

cv2.imshow('Feature Method - FAST', image)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a mask to remove the areas you are not interested. For example with the following image as a mask you can get the bellow results.

[Mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFuaq.jpg)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrhoT.jpg)

Code is as follow:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
image = cv2.imread('test.jpg')
mask = cv2.imread('mask.jpg', 0)
cv2.imshow('Original', image)
cv2.imshow('Mask', mask)
res = cv2.bitwise_and(image,image,mask = mask)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(res, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

fast = cv2.FastFeatureDetector_create()
# Obtain Key points, by default non max suppression is On
# to turn off set fast.setBool('nonmaxSuppression', False)
keypoints = fast.detect(gray, None)
print ("Number of keypoints Detected: ", len(keypoints))

image = cv2.drawKeypoints(image, keypoints, None, 
                      flags=cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

cv2.imwrite('result.jpg', image)
cv2.imshow('Feature Method - FAST', image)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Edit:
If you want to do this in realtime (video from webcam) you just need to do it for every frame you get from the video camera. As long as the camera is not moving you should be able to use the same mask for all the frames. You could make the code above a function and then call it with an image as a parameter, as per the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Following function will have to be created with the previews code
    CallFunctionToPreviewsCode(frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The code above was taken from [OpenCV Python-Tutorials](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html) It is a good place for learning OpenCV for Python programming language.

Comment: Yes that would be a solution. The problem is, the picture is just an example of what I want, in the application I'll have to do this in a live recording. Thats where my brain have forsaken me.

Comment: I have edited my answer for what I understand you are asking for. As long as the camera is not moving you should be fine otherwise things do get more complicated.

Comment: Thank you so much for your aswer/time. Your solution really did  the job. Thanks!